Which Execution Provider is this using?
I'm currently running a roop face swapper,  I'm a little bit confuse which execution provider is this using?
my CPU Utilisation is 100%, but it says it's using CUDAExecutionProvider (gpu) in the end, but it's weird that I can use my PC like usual (opening blender etc. without lagging while it says my CPU Util 100%. enlighten me please?

Applied providers: ['CPUExecutionProvider'], with options: {'CPUExecutionProvider': {}}
inswapper-shape: [1, 3, 128, 128]
Processing:  60%|█████▉    | 2160/3607 [1:00:36<44:19,  1.84s/frame, memory_usage=02.44GB, execution_providers=['CUDAExecutionProvider'], execution_threads=4]

I've tried to use CUDA as default, does it mean it's working? because my GPU is not showing any load in task manager, but my CPU is showing 100%, but I don't feel any lag. Thank you!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
